# Cannot toggle full screen video element with Javascript on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, hls.js

I have a basic video element with HLS.js

I cannot program it to open full screen with javascript

I have tried webkitRequestFullscreen(),webkitEnterFullscreen(), tried adding allowfullscreen to the markup, to no avail

Where am I going wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that 's possible, Chrome is blocking it and it can be done only with user event (e.g. click), otherwise there would be fullscreen ads all over the place.

Comment: thanks,it is just a personal project, is there maybe a flag I can enable to allow this? I guess changing the css to full screen might distort the quality of the video?

Comment: The trick is to go into fullscreen mode on the `click()` that loads the video, and then load the video into the already fullScreen. jCobb is correct in that this requires user action in Chrome. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Randy, can you clarify your solution please, I am pretty amateur.

Comment: I tried Randy's approach before I post, you can't, chrome prevents the method on click event handler :(

Comment: Thanks jCobb, is it possible if I can programmatically give the video element focus, and then use a keyboard shortcut to open fullscreen?

Comment: I don't like giving up either, but I think this would be hacky solution and even if you find some workaround, chrome devs would patch it asap :(